# Create outlook macro that runs for every user

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to create a macro in outlook that prompts every user while sending emails. I have the code and it works fine for me, but when I log in using different account, the macro doesn't work. Can we build any c# application for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you implementing it? Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can develop an Outlook add-in which can be installed for all users on the PC. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started quickly.